# How can I make it so that only one thread can view a local json file at a time

Tags: python, json, asynchronous, electron, queue

Hi i am currently developing a project the outline is below

3-10 selenium browsers
each browser monitors the same queue.json file
if the queue.json file has something in it ONE of the selenium browsers needs to then get a url

Currently this python script is connected to a simple electronjs GUI using python shell
when i click a button the gui it runs a async function that opens a selenium browser
the selenium browser then just loops in a while True loop monitoring the queue.json file

the issue is that when i add something to the queue.json file multiple selenium browsers will pick up the same item in the queue before the browser can remove the item from queue

is there any way that i can make it so that queue.json can only be accessed by one browser at a time

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a `Lock`.

A lock allows you to access data from many threads without them all accessing at the same time. When one thread is holding on the the lock no other thread can use it until the initial thread releases the lock.

```py
from threading import Lock

l = Lock()

with l:
    # access json queue
```

#### Use python's `Queue`

you can put the data in python's `threading.Queue`; It's thread safe

```py
from threading import Queue
```